# Wait for functions to finish then return object

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I want to return newly updated object. But when I try to assign values with pipe chained methods, it doesn't work and returns initial values.

What is the better way to assign with chained functions and return object ?

Here is the code:

```
currentUser: UserInterface = {
    accessToken: '',
    userID: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    picture: '',
    pageList: [],
    activePageID: 0,
    activePage: {
      name: '',
      pageID: '',
      instagramID: '',
      categoryID: '',
      tasks: [],
    },
  };

  login(user: FacebookLoginInterface) {
      this.generateLongUserToken(user.accessToken).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.currentUser.accessToken = response.access_token;
        this.getUserPages(this.currentUser.accessToken).pipe(
          map((response) => {
            this.currentUser.pageList = response;
            this.getInstagramBusinessAccount(
              this.currentUser.pageList[0].id,
              this.currentUser.accessToken,
            ).pipe(
              map((response) => {
                this.currentUser.activePage.instagramID =
                  response.instagram_business_account.id;
              }),
            );
          }),
        );
      }),
    ); 

    return {
      access_token: this.currentUser,
    };
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is a "pipe chained method". That's not a native javascript/typescript concept as far as I'm aware.

Comment: "Pipe" is also not a NextJS concept. At least not that I'm aware... You're calling `this.generateLongUserToken(user.accessToken)`. What does that method return?

Comment: @Elias I am developing in "nestjs". It returns a new long live token when I give a short lived token. What I want is: There are 2-3 methods that return values from facebook api. And I need to assign them to their counterparts in "currentUser". But it doesnt wait for them to finish and returns "currentUser" instantly or assigning counterparts in methods doesn't work.

Comment: Mh, what is the typescript type it returns?

Comment: If `this.generateLongUserToken(user.accessToken)`returns `UserInterface` shouldn't there be a `pipe` function on that interface?

Comment: @Elias sorry I didn't understand correctly. This is what longusertoken returns.
export interface LongUserTokenInterface {
  access_token: string;
  token_type: string;
  expires_in: number;
}

Comment: Yeah, see, I cannot really help you because I don't know what that `pipe` call is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises

```
login() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.generateLongUserToken(user.accessToken).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.currentUser.accessToken = response.access_token;
        this.getUserPages(this.currentUser.accessToken).pipe(
          map((response) => {
            this.currentUser.pageList = response;
            this.getInstagramBusinessAccount(
              this.currentUser.pageList[0].id,
              this.currentUser.accessToken,
            ).pipe(
              map((response) => {
                this.currentUser.activePage.instagramID =
                  response.instagram_business_account.id;
                // If I understand correctly, at this point `currentUser`
                // is ready to be returned, so resolve the promise here
                resolve() 
              }),
            );
          }),
        );
      }),
    ); 
  }).then(() => ({
    access_token: this.currentUser,
  }))
}

currentUser.login().then(user => {
  // Here user is updated
})
```

Also you could clean it up a bit to have less levels of nesting

```
login() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.generateLongUserToken(user.accessToken).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.currentUser.accessToken = response.access_token;
        resolve(response.access_token)
      })
    )
  }).then((accessToken) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.getUserPages(this.currentUser.accessToken).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.currentUser.pageList = response;
        resolve({pageList: response, accessToken})
      })
    )
  })).then(({pageList, accessToken}) => new Promise(resolve => {
      this.getInstagramBusinessAccount(
        this.currentUser.pageList[0].id,
        this.currentUser.accessToken,
      ).pipe(
        map((response) => {
          this.currentUser.activePage.instagramID =
              response.instagram_business_account.id;
          resolve()
        })
      )
  })).then(() => ({
    access_token: this.currentUser,
  }))
}
```

Except this will only work if function in `map` will be called once. The name `map` suggests that callback may be called multiple times, in this case this won't work as well. Anyway, you should use promises